# R MARKDOWN nao está exportando para nenhum opcão

Tags: ggplot2, rmarkdown

**Estou utilizando o RMarkdown e meus graficos estão aparecendo durante a execução dos códigos porém quando clico no knit para exporar para uma das opcoes aparece a seguinte mensagem:**

*Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") :
trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls:  ... withvisible -> eval -> eval -> install.packages -> contrib.url
Execucao interrompida*

Comment: Benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Você tem uma linha com a execução `contrib.url`que está gerando conflito. Comente esta linha para executar o Knitr.

Comment: @DanielIkenaga Consigo enviar a imagem do Erro para que você veja se consegue me ajudar? No meu mba falaram para eu atualizar meu R o pacote. Já fiz e a mensagem é a mesma. Ele diz que o erro é na contrib.url  na linha 9. A linha 9 eu tenho essa instalacao.
install.packages("tidyverse")

Comment: Remova ou comente `#` as linhas de install.packages() no seu script do RMarkdown. Se o pacote está instalado, não precisa fazer a instalação novamente.